# AngujarJS - ngRoute/ngView - stacked views

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm new to Angular and it's my first time using the ng-view directive. I'm developing a Phonegap application and I noticed that, upon clicking many consecutive links which do a:

```
$location.path('/somePath') //this is illustrative - path depends on link clicked
```

the new loaded view is stacked. This means: I have to click the back-arrow in my android device N+1 times to leave the program, if I followed N links (or N calls to `$location.path`). Althought this behavior is not expected for me (I'm a n00b here), looks good in the base user experience I need for my app (is it related to the history stack?) - but also I have a "go to main menu" button, and I want that button "clearing such stack", rolling back to the first screen.

Why do I need it? Because I was navigating in my app back-and-forth (currently my "go to main menu" button does `$location.path('/')`, which STACKS again a main-menu view) and when I tried to close my application using the back-arrow button I had to hit that button an annoying amount of times.

So: how do I clear the stack when I click the main-menu button? (instead of doing `$location.path('/')`)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a phonegap app then I am assuming the actual URL doesn't matter to you?  You may want to look at the ui-router module instead of ng-route as it focuses more on states than simple routes.  You can easily move to/from states, with transitions if necessary, without changing the $location at all (avoiding your problem).  Additionally, ui-router supports named views and nested views so you can split your templates up into smaller pieces if that fits your project.

Sorry not a direct answer to your question, but it sounds like ui-router is a better tool for what you are trying to do.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: I must have this solved in record time. How can I pop all states from a view using ui-router? The UX will be horrible if they navigate a lot and want to click "go back" to exit, and find they must click the button many times. How is the ui-router different in **that** matter?

Comment: Changing $location.path is just like navigating to a new page.  It puts it into the browser history just as navigating regular links would and the back button goes back one.  The way ui-router solves this is by allowing you to change the state without having to change the path (or the browser history).  If your app needs to support deep linking then there's no real way around it since you'll need to change the browser's url.